# Multiple PHP Variables in SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

Im struggling to understand quotes in PHP Mainly when doing SQL Query's. I keep getting an 
error on this query.

```
SELECT Hotels.HotelImage1, Holidays.ID, Hotels.HotelName, Destinations.Name, PriceBands.PriceBand_Cost FROM Holidays
INNER JOIN Hotels ON Holidays.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID
INNER JOIN PriceBands ON Holidays.PriceBand_ID = PriceBands.ID
INNER JOIN Destinations ON Destinations.ID = Holidays.Destination_ID
WHERE Destinations.ID = ".$dest."AND Hotels.ID =".$hotel;
```

I'm Trying to use two PHP variables in the query. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You might need to add a space after `.$dest."` so it's separate from the following AND, but that's just a guess.

Comment: probably going to be safer to use the PDO prepared Statements.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php can you update the question with more of your code?

Comment: dest and hotel probably need quotes, too.

Comment: @user623952 - possibly, though they're both looking for an ID field; I'd assume it's numeric, but I've been on SO long enough to never take that sort of thing for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
$query = "SELECT Hotels.HotelImage1, Holidays.ID, Hotels.HotelName, Destinations.Name, PriceBands.PriceBand_Cost FROM Holidays
INNER JOIN Hotels ON Holidays.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID
INNER JOIN PriceBands ON Holidays.PriceBand_ID = PriceBands.ID
INNER JOIN Destinations ON Destinations.ID = Holidays.Destination_ID
WHERE Destinations.ID = '$dest' AND Hotels.ID = '$hotel'";
```

Since you are using ID and if it is an integer field, it is not required to put quotes around ID value, you can also do

```
$query = "SELECT Hotels.HotelImage1, Holidays.ID, Hotels.HotelName, Destinations.Name, PriceBands.PriceBand_Cost FROM Holidays
INNER JOIN Hotels ON Holidays.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID
INNER JOIN PriceBands ON Holidays.PriceBand_ID = PriceBands.ID
INNER JOIN Destinations ON Destinations.ID = Holidays.Destination_ID
WHERE Destinations.ID = $dest AND Hotels.ID = $hotel";
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to escape the query input. You can esacpe the user input using two methods. Using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

**With mysqli_real_escape :**

```
$dest  = $mysqli->real_escape_string($dest);
$hotel = $mysqli->real_escape_string($hotel);

$stmt = "SELECT Hotels.HotelImage1, Holidays.ID, Hotels.HotelName, Destinations.Name, PriceBands.PriceBand_Cost FROM Holidays
    INNER JOIN Hotels ON Holidays.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID
    INNER JOIN PriceBands ON Holidays.PriceBand_ID = PriceBands.ID
    INNER JOIN Destinations ON Destinations.ID = Holidays.Destination_ID
    WHERE Destinations.ID = '$dest' AND Hotels.ID = '$hotel'";
```

**With Prepared statement :**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Hotels.HotelImage1, Holidays.ID, Hotels.HotelName, Destinations.Name, PriceBands.PriceBand_Cost FROM Holidays
    INNER JOIN Hotels ON Holidays.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID
    INNER JOIN PriceBands ON Holidays.PriceBand_ID = PriceBands.ID
    INNER JOIN Destinations ON Destinations.ID = Holidays.Destination_ID
    WHERE Destinations.ID = ? AND Hotels.ID = ?");

/* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $dest, $hotel);
```

Comment: it's for a college assignment we dont need to go that deep. we do that next semester

Answer (score 0):

Try change last string to

```
WHERE Destinations.ID = '".$dest."' AND Hotels.ID ='".$hotel."'";
```

And always show sql errors. It is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

SQL (Most flavours, anyways) requires that strings be delimited by single-quotes.  You have to build this into your query.  Also, don't bother concatenating the variables as PHP is capable of finding variables inside strings.

Answer (score 0):

Do not build SQL queries that way. Use Prepared Statements instead. Its parameter bind avoids any issue related to the data-type, SQL injection attacks and any security stuff.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php